# Как в NavigationView добавить custom item программамно?

Tags: android

Как в NavigationView добавить custom item программамно?,  создав свой адаптер, можно пример

Comment: Пример адаптера или что?

Comment: мне нужно item  c с двумя  TextView,  я адаптер смогу создать, как его подключить ?

Comment: подключить к `NavigationView`, как вы хотите это сделать? Насколько я знаю `NavigationView`, работает только с  menu-res из xml

Comment: как мне тогда добавить список custom item с  двумя TextView и ImageView,  к-ые я  получаю с сервера

Comment: Вам нужно не использовать NavigationView, а вставить туда например ListView или RecyclerView и вставить туда все, что хотите

Comment: Спасибо попробую так сделать

Comment: Не использую `NavigationView` из-за его ограниченности

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Вам нужно не использовать NavigationView, а вставить туда например ListView или RecyclerView и вставить туда все, что хотите. Не использую NavigationView из-за его ограниченности" georgehardcore 7